# SpringSecurity select authentication provider by prefix

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I have a Spring REST-API which is secured by SpringSecurity.

I have different ways to authenticate in that application.

- Customer (db)
- Employees (ldap)
- Other Applications/Services (inMemory)

Each of these are covered by a different authentication provider, which properly assigns the access roles. (Works)

However I need to know which authentication provider was used to  authenticate the user, so I can write it to the logs, history...

`User CUSTOMER/max.pain created a new entry.`

And of course the username does not really contain that prefix, neither in the db, nor in ldap.

I considered adding a special role based on the authentication provider used, but extracting that information over and over is annoying and probably has bad performance and might cause problems in the future. (`user.getGrantedAuthorities().findStartingWith("AP_")`)

I also tried using `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.addObjectPostProcessor(ObjectPostProcessor<?>)` but i cannot use it to wrap the AuthenticationProvider with a custom AuthenticationProvider class, because it requires the use the [same class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java#L376-L377) for whatever reason.

Is there an inbuild method I could use to achieve that or do I have to use a custom implementation/configuration?

---

Prozess steps:

1. Login: EMPLOYEE/always.calm
2. Don't check CUSTOMER AuthenticationProvider
3. Check EMPLOYEE AuthenticationProvider
4. Don't check SERVICE AuthenticationProvider
5. authentication.getPrincipal().getAP() = EMPLOYEE

Comment: in our firm, we are setting a MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Contexts) for such purposes. The context is assigned by the provider for the current thread, and must be manually cleared at the end of the request. The context doesn't display in the message of the logs, but is somehow attached to the next log statements. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html and can be retrieved with a log viewer (logstash and kibana for example)

Comment: ... then you can add a column with your custom field in your view, for example: ```thread: http-1, authenticator: ldap, username: max.pain, message: blabla``` . I don't know if you have all the tooling required to display it this way, but MDC is really a good option to investigate.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question right, but you can store that information in your `UserDetails`. For example you can implement a custom `UserDetails` object.

Comment: Its not about storing the information. I need to obtain the information which AuthenticationProvider authenticated the user.